# Always prompting of log in information for users

Tags: sharepoint

I have a requirement to always prompting of log in information for users in SharePoint site rather than taking their logged in credentials.

Any idea??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the setup you have.
You could just remove the SharePoint site from the trusted sites or local intranet under IE's security tab using a group policy. 
This will cause a prompt every time they go to the site.

you need to reverse the steps found [here](http://kb.onenet.co.nz/?View=entry&EntryID=90)

Regards,
Vince

Comment: This solution might be perfect for single user. If there are set of users who access same site, what will happen? Do the configuration in all individual machine is not practical. I want to know is there any configuration related to this in SharePoint. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can roll out the solution to all the machines on the network using a group policy in AD.
Here is a nice link for individual and Group http://sharepointinnovations.blogspot.com/2013/05/remember-user-name-and-password-for.html